# Is it possible to prevent the deletion of the documents under specific collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a lot of accounts inside a collection called `Users` and I want to prevent the deletion of the documents (accounts), How can I do it using rules security?

Also, I want to ask is it possible to prevent deleting any document inside Users collection via `Firebase Console`?

I don't need to delete any document never even by the admin

---

**Edit Rules History**

```
//Before pusblish the question
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}

//Current
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /USERS/{userId} {
      allow delete: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `write` rule can be broken into `create`, `update`, and `delete`. You can prevent deletion of documents using these security rules:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow delete: if false;
}
```

Checkout the documentation of security rules [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations).

---

You cannot prevent deletion of documents from the Firebase console (but best to prevent anyone unauthorized to access that at first place).

---

Your previous security rules were insecure and allowed anyone to read/update/delete any collection. The updates rules only specify that no one is allowed to delete the documents in users collection but there's no condition for read operations and for other collections. You should explicitly define them as shown below:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /USERS/{userId} {
      allow read: true;
      allow delete: if false;
    }

    match /Transactions/{txnId} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules allow anyone to read users collection but not delete any document and read/write any document in Transactions collection. I would recommend checking out [Get to know Cloud Firestore - Security Rules](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eW5MdE3ZcAw) and writing secure rules as per your use case.

Comment: `If false` command, Could you tell me what is it?

Comment: @Iuq281 so when the condition of `allow delete:` or any operation results in true then that operation is allowed. But if you set that to false yourself then there's no chance it'll ever be true and will not allow delete.

Comment: But now I cannot delete any document even in other collections that are outside Users collection - `PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

Comment: @Iuq281 do notice I have `match /users/{userId}` so these rules are applicable for users collection only. Can you please edit and update your question with what rules you had before updating based on my answer and what rules you have now?

Comment: Check now. I'm trying to delete a document inside the `Transactions` collection that are outside the `Users` collection but can't delete the document

Comment: @Iuq281 I've updated my answer. You essentially have to specify rules separately for other collections.

Comment: Error saving rules – Line 5: Missing 'if' before conditional expression.; Line 10: Missing 'if' before conditional expression.

Comment: @Iuq281 yes I missed an `if` in the transactions block. Can you please add it as in my updated answer?

Comment: Check at line 5 also. It's working now but what about canceling deleting also from Firebase Console, Is it not possible to do it? I'm afraid the admin delete the user account unintentionally

Comment: Thank you. Don't forget to fix `allow read: true;` to `allow read: if true;` at line 5

Comment: There's no way to prevent deleting data when you have editor access. You can learn more about basic roles in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-basic) and try viewer role

Comment: I'll check now, Thank you